# Syntax Error Java Script code cuenta de restaurante

Tags: javascript, html, html5

estoy ejecutando este código y realmente no encuentro el error... Me gustaría conocer màs puntos de vista o sugerencias para que resulte la ejecución del código sin error. De antemano gracias!:)

En la siguiente imagen, tax es el impuesto y bill es mi gasto total (sin impuesto agregado), al sumar tax a bill debería obtener el total definitivo y dividirlo entre 5 (necesariamente), así el resultado de esto cerraría mi test. Sin embargo, al plantearlo de esta forma aún me indica que existe un error :/[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Agregue **parseInt** para mantener el valor de mis variables como números enteros. Me queda la duda de si es correcto o debería usar otra función ¿?
2. Esta es la respuesta que arroja la plataforma **lms** dónde estoy realizando el test. 
   Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

RESTAURANTBILL()
DEBERÍA REGRESAR $11, PARA 50
expected 55 to deeply equal '$11'

DEBERÍA REGRESAR $22, PARA 100
expected 110 to deeply equal '$22'

DEBERÍA REGRESAR $18.7, PARA 85
expected 93.5 to deeply equal '$18.7'

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo en vez de una imagen?, intentastes que el resultado te devuelva valores enteros sospecho que es por como lo devuelve

Comment: Winnie!, es mejor agregar el código como texto no como imagen, revisa [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que el problema, bastante típico cuando se está depurando, viene de que por un lado muestras una información en la consola, y por el otro, retornas un valor distinto. Así, con `console.log()` muestras `total/5`, lo cual según tu pregunta parece ser la respuesta correcta, mientras estás retornando *total* (y no *total/5*), lo cuál explicaría que los *tests* no pasaran.

Yo cambiaría el código a:

```
var tax = bill * .1;
var total = parseInt( bill + tax ) / 5;

console.log('$', total);
return total;
```

...retornando lo mismo que muestras.

Comment: aunque tu respuesta puede que este bien , esto promueve a realizar malas preguntas mira [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @JackNavaRow me parece excesivo valorar negativamente una respuesta solo por eso. Considero que es la pregunta, y no la respuesta, la que debería tener el voto negativo. 
Además, según el enlace que nos has facilitado, el único criterio por el que podría no responderse a la pregunta es "son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real." y esto es un poco contradictorio con el hecho de que el usuario haya sido capaz de encontrar fácilmente la respuesta a la pregunta (la diferencia de tiempo de pregunta y respuesta es tan solo de una hora).

Comment: @RobertoPintosLópez vamos al [chat]